# How to place 3d model in arcore with accurate size of 3d model in real life

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I want to place a chair in arcore with actual size of chair in real life.  The user should not able to zoom in or zoom out that chair in arcore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate system in world space uses meters as the units. So if you create your model in Blender with 1 unit height it is 1 meter.
You can disable scaleController in [TransformableNode](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode) to disable scaling:

> node.scaleController.isEnabled = false